# Isuue Regarding Login Agent

Tags: rdp, rpa, blueprism, vdi

We are using Is Logged In action from Log In VBO to check if bot is logged in the VDI or not, this action was always returning True value on our development Machine, But this action  Doesn't works on Client VDI it is always returning false. We are using Blue Prism version 6.7.3 and hence we have installed Login Agent by using the exe which was provided with Blue Prism installation, but still this action returns false value, leading to process termination in debug mode. Can someone please suggest any troubleshooting steps so that this action works on our development VDI.

I have kept the Screen shot of it even Please let help us if any similar kind of scenario any one might faced

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Login Agent Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104296/login-agent-issue)

Answer (score 0):

If the Is Logged In action is returning false this indicates that the Runtime Resource is not logged in and you need to run the "Log In" action. I would use a passive remote connection tool like VNC to view the Runtime Resource side by side with the Blue Prism application to see what is happening on the Runtime Resource and also what the status of the Runtime Resource is in control room. A few things to check would be;

Name Resolution

- Can the Runtime ping the Application Server by hostname?
- Can the Application Server ping the Runtime Resource?

Runtime Resource Control Room Status

- Is the Runtime Resource State showing as logged out with the Key icon in control room?
- Is the Runtime Resource Connection showing as connected or not connected in control room?